# Grouping image by data from csv

Tags: python, csv, dataset

I'm new to Python. I have many images in the same folder, and I want to group them into subfolders by data in my CSV file. My CSV file has two columns (id and breed) like this:

```
id,breed
nameroot_of_image_01,bulldog
nameroot_of_image_02,dingo
nameroot_of_image_03,otterhound
nameroot_of_image_04,otterhound
```

and my images that are in the same folder with files named like this:

```
nameroot_of_image_01.jpg
nameroot_of_image_02.jpg
nameroot_of_image_03.jpg
nameroot_of_image_04.jpg
```

I want each image that has the same breed put into the same folder, and the folder name is the breed name. Is there any Python code that will group my files according to the csv above?

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) are your friend here.

Let's assume the csv file is named `breeds.csv` in the current working directory

```sh
$ cat breeds.csv
id,breed
nameroot_of_image_01,bulldog
nameroot_of_image_02,dingo
nameroot_of_image_03,otterhound
nameroot_of_image_04,otterhound
```

And the image files are in the same directory

```
$ ls .
breeds.csv  nameroot_of_image_01.jpg  nameroot_of_image_02.jpg  nameroot_of_image_03.jpg  nameroot_of_image_04.jpg
```

A working script is shown below.
Before running this make sure:

- you're using python 3.6+
- this script is also in the directory with the csv and the image
  files
- Have installed pandas via pip or conda

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Imports 
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# Step 1 - read in the csv file
# 'header=0' here ensures that the first row is used as column names
breeds_df = pd.read_csv("breeds.csv", header=0)

# Step 2 - iterate through each row and move the file to the breeds directory
for index, row in breeds_df.iterrows():
    # Get image path in cwd
    image_path = Path("{}.jpg".format(row["id"]))

    # Check file exists, skip otherwise
    if not image_path.is_file():
        print("Could not find file {}. Skipping...".format(image_path))
        continue
    
    # Check breed folder exists, create if not
    breed_dir = Path(row["breed"])
    if not breed_dir.is_dir():
        breed_dir.mkdir()

    # Move file over from current directory to breed subdirectory
    image_path.rename(breed_dir / image_path.name)
```